# Someone using BreezeStyleSheets with PyQt6 here? How to?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6, qtstylesheets

Using *PyQt6* on *Python-3.11.* Coding with pycharm.

Have some problem with understanding how to use Alexhuszagh's BreezeStyleSheets - https://github.com/Alexhuszagh/BreezeStyleSheets

I downloaded full code as a zip, then placed folder from the archive inside my project folder, full path for folder is like `D:\My\Project\BreezeStyleSheets` and all that `assets`, `dist`, etc. folders inside.

Then I'm going to this part: https://github.com/Alexhuszagh/BreezeStyleSheets#pyqt6-installation

I created an empty `test.py` file inside the project (it is on one level with `BreezeStyleSheets` folder) and placed there:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    # Either option is valid here.
    #   Either use `package_data` with enumerating the values, or
    #   set `include_package_data=True`.
    # include_package_data=True,
    package_data={
        "breeze_theme": ["BreezeStyleSheets/dist/pyqt6/*"],
    },
    zip_safe=False,
)
```

And it crashes with:

```
usage: test.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: test.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: test.py --help-commands
   or: test.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
```

Where I'm incorrect in what I'm doing?

**PS** I tried commenting `include_package_data` or `package_data` rows, nothing changed.

Update1: TY for help, I tried it and find that it's not that what I want to.

Comment: It's unclear and unspecific. See [ask]. Research enough. Did you build the library with the ```python configure.py ...``` command? Are you sure you are creating a Python package(that can be distributed via PyPI)? If it's not, just load from a directory, like ```QDir.addSearchPath('dark', 'LIBRARY_SOURCE_ROOT/dist/pyqt6/dark'); file = QFile("dark:stylesheet.qss")```.

Comment: Hi @relent95. Sorry for that, but I provided link on instruction I'm trying to do. I never used setuptools before. That's really ALL I can say about the moment. Thanks, I'll try to load without packing.

Comment: You imply you are not creating a Python package? That link says "Since pyrcc is no longer being maintained, using local Python paths is the preferable solution." It's not saying you have to  package your code using setuptools.

Comment: @relent95 and on next line: `First, package your code using setuptools.`

Comment: That paragraph is the continuation of the "For a detailed description on how to package these resources, see this StackOverflow answer.". It's a small project. Don't expect high quality documentation. You may contribute to the documentation in [here](https://github.com/Alexhuszagh/BreezeStyleSheets/issues).

Comment: NP, I already tried it and find that pyqtdarktheme looks better on my project. (and this thing eats alot of space...)